# Anticipating new role at current company

Tags: professionalism, career-development, new-job

I am been given the hint that I may be looked at favorably for a Sales role in my current company. I have been with this company for under a year in a support function. Although a sales role is not in line with my career plans, I do see the upside of stepping into a sales role.

My question is this:
Should I approach my manager and express my intent or at least have a discussion? OR
Should I wait for them to approach me? Considering that they might when the time is right.

My biggest concern is not to come across as somebody who wants to change jobs too soon.

Comment: Who has given you this hint? Your manager or somebody else?

Comment: @Glorfindel Manager, colleagues

Comment: from person experience, express interest. People may say you probably fit the role and such, but unless you actually agree or show that you wouldn't mind taking on the role, they may think that you're uninterested and will hand it off to someone who is eager to get into the role. So it's an opportunity you shouldn't miss. And if the role is within your company, I wouldn't really consider that 'changing jobs' since it's just changing roles which happens a lot, though usually without title changes.

Answer (score 0):

**Wait it out**.  Never start what might end up being an official discussion based in rumors from dubious sources.  If it happens, it happens.  If not, you haven't stuck your neck out on something that may have absolutely no basis in reality, given the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in a new position, ask about the new position!

1. Never wait for somebody to ask you.  You'll always be waiting.
2. Don't seek a position "just for the money"
3. If you have a bona fide reason to ask if you'd be good at sales, why wouldn't you ask?

**Waiting**

Waiting is appropriate at times, especially when you don't deserve something.  However, looking for a new position or new responsibility is not something you need to wait for somebody to ask you about.  Ask yourself if a manager would be happy having you on the sales team.  Would you be successful?  Would you be an asset to the sales team?  Many times, there isn't a "open position", the position is there for you to open the door.

**Never go after it for the money**

It is rare for a professional to be able to change themselves to fit a new job.  Your question about this situation makes me wonder if you really want this type of job.  Why are you seeking a sales job?  You wrote that it was not in your "plan".  Is that because it is not a job you respect? enjoy?  Many people consider sales for the money.  Is that really what you want?  Can you be successful at a job that is not in your plan just for the money?

**Don't base you search on rumors, base it on whether or not you'd be good at the job**

Nobody I know wants to give somebody a job because they are *rumored* to be good at it.  They want people that *will* be good at it!  If you will be good at sales, then you have a legitimate reason to inquire.  I would ask a manager in sales:

1. What is a sales job like in this company?
2. How do I develop the skills to be good at sales?
3. Do you think I'd be good at sales?

There is no reason for a Sales Manager to lie about these things.  If it wasn't in your plan, I'm assuming you don't have much experience in sales.  Find out if this is a commissioned position, a salaried position, whether you have quotas to meet, how you close a deal, how you get paid or get credit for a sale, ...

**Disregard the rumor**

Consider the rumor as flattery and nothing else.  Play it straight.  Be sincere.  Ignore the politics.  If you're working for a profitable, reputable, commercial entity then they will reward success.  Focus on whether or not you'd be successful and happy at sales, regardless of the rumor.  Once you've re-oriented yourself to the right path without the rumor, you'll find your proper direction and know what to do.

Comment: Thanks so much.  What if I am feeling a strong sense of "being pushed" into this new sales role? How should I be starting this discussion myself, given the fact that waiting may not be an option here?  The honest truth is that this role is not in my career path but there are elements of this role that might add value to my career. So a lot of things will need to fall in line for me: 1. Compensation: I should be rewarded for my efforts 2. Title: If my title shows up as top salesy, I think this might cause people to question my move. 3. Visibility of what this role might grow into

Comment: Who is doing the *pushing*?  It seems that the person pushing is not the manager that would hire.  Why aren't you talking to the person that would be your future boss?  Seems like you're afraid to talk to the sales manager.  If so, talk to one of their staff; talk to the existing sales person.  Ask them "What is it like?"  "What do you do day to day?" "How is sales compensated?"  With many sales jobs, people are paid commission.  This means a percentage of the value of the sale.  For some people that's too much pressure to earn a "salary". <BTW vote for the answer that works for your question>